# What are the different types of catalysts used in catalytic hydrogenation of alkynes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, organic-reduction

This is a question from Org. Chem. by Solomons, Fryhle & Snyder, adapted for JEE by M.S. Chouhan :

> [image]

1. In the first step, I expected that the reaction would stop at alkene formation via syn addition of $\ce{H_2}$ since Lindlar catalyst is poisobed and heterogeneous. What are some other other poisoned catalysts that stop at alkene?
2. In the second step, I expected syn addition of $\ce{D_2}$ since $\ce{Pd-C}$ is a heterogeneous catalyst, forming product (a). But the answer given is (c) — does this mean that some heterogeneous catalyts can give anti addition, or is it just an error on the adapting author's part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The "Lindlar catalyst" (Pd/CaCO<sub>3</sub>) is probably the most common way of effecting stereoselective reduction of alkynes to (*Z*)-alkenes. It is fairly accessible and the reaction is easy to run. But it is not the only way: there are other catalyst systems. One of the more notable ones is probably the Brown catalyst "P2-Ni" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_boride#Catalytic_hydrogenation)).

   There is a nice review on alkyne semihydrogenation here: [*Chem. Rev.* **2013,** *113* (3), 1313–1350](https://doi.org/10.1021/cr3001753), which covers both heterogeneous and homogeneous methods, as well as methods involving other hydrogen sources apart from H<sub>2</sub> gas itself. I recommend it to interested readers and especially anybody considering carrying out such a reduction.

---

2. The Lindlar hydrogenation of an alkyne forms (*Z*)-alkenes stereoselectively. *Syn* hydrogenation of the (*Z*)-alkene gives product (c), not product (a).

   [image: Reaction scheme]

   Note that in the fully reduced alkane, there is free rotation about the central C–C bond. So, having both D atoms pointing "out of the plane" is irrelevant, as you can easily rotate to a conformation in which one D atom is pointing in the plane. However, the configuration of the product cannot be changed, and that is the difference between options (a) and (c).